# C equivalent to Python crypto.crypto()

Tags: python, c++, c, cryptography, sha512

Is there any C or C++ function which can produce the same output of this python code (SHA512 with salt)?

```python
import crypt;
crypt.crypt('test', '$6$Salte2Ck$')
```

Comment: There's no such function in standard C or C++. You have to use an external library.

Comment: Related: [How to calculate a SHA-512 hash in C++ on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5125041/279627)

Comment: any idea where to find portable external library which can do the same job? or do I need to write my own SHA512+ salt?

Comment: Here's how `crypt.crypt()` is implemented: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/50722d2f08c7/Modules/cryptmodule.c  It basically simply forwards to the C library function `crypt()`.

Comment: Why do you think Python's crypt uses SHA512?  It doesn't seem to do so, both according to the implementation and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html).

Comment: because when I use this python function it produce the same hash value as SHA512

Comment: @Sven:  Unfortunately Python's crypt documentation is inadequate and incomplete.  That's probably somewhat intentional because the underlying `crypt` function is [underspecified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/crypt.html) and its implementation depends on your platform and even OS version.  In fact, on my (older) Linux system, it's impossible to get `crypt` to use SHA-512, but that's not true on all versions of Linux.

Comment: @indiv: I think the Python documentation is quite clear that this function simply forwards to `crypt(3)`.  It even refers to the man page and mentions that details are different from platform to platform.  What else would you hope for?

Comment: @sven I don't know, you are the one who said the documentation didn't say it used SHA-512 even though it does in this case and I was explaining why.  But if you think the documentation is fine then that's ok too.

Comment: @indiv: I wasn't aware that there are systems where `crypt` is based on SHA512.  It certainly isn't on any system I ever used.

Comment: I believe it deepen on the second parameter sent to this function.For example, calHash= crypt.crypt(input,'$6$m90MgTxl$') the $6$ in the second parameter is for SHA512 and I can verify this by checking the /etc/shadow file in my Ubuntu system which contain the passwords hash for all the users. when I call this function with the same salt and password the result is the same as the hash saved in the /etc/shadow file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052047/python-crypt-in-osx) are some explanations to Python's `crypt` function.
So I think what you are looking for is the C function `crypt` from `unistd.h`.